# Is it possible to assign a 'hidden' string to a certain string in a listbox in a MATLAB GUI?

Tags: matlab

Hopefully I can make my question clearer: I am creating a sub GUI in MATLAB to be called by the main GUI. In this sub GUI I will have a listbox, with various different strings, such as 'Impedance' or 'Bandwidth'. I know how to get the GUI to return these values, but what I actually want it to return, for example, is 'imp' and 'bw' to match with variable names I already have in my program. I know I could implement this with if else statements, but I was wondering if there was a more concise way of doing this, so it would automatically give me the strings that correspond with variable names straight away.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

listbox actually returns a numeric value that is the index of the selected item.
Then if you want the selected string item you have first to get the String property (a cell array of strings) and then you can use the `{}` indexing.
Now if you wants a different string to correspond to each item all you have to do is to create another cell array of strings with the requested correspondence. So in code

```
set(yourListHandle,'String',{'Impedance','Bandwidth'});
ShortCut = {'imp','bw'};
%//---Manual selction operations---
%//
String = get(yourListHandle,'String');
I = get(yourStringHandle,'Value');

%//the selected item is
String{I}

%//the selected item short cut is
ShortCut{I}
```

The thing to be careful of here is that if you reorder the list withing you listbox then you will have to reorder also the ShortCut list.